# How to create a chart displaying the number of bugs created per week?

Tags: tfs

In my company we are using TFS 2015.

I want to add a chart displaying the number of items created during one week, for the last 4 weeks (or 12 weeks), not the number of items created only during the past 7 days. It's easy to get the items counter; so in other words I would like the first derivative of this curve. I cannot figure out how to get this.

I've tried to use the field `Created Date > @Today-7` and `Created Date <= @Today`, but the query does apply only for current week.

Is it possible to get this trend chart?

Comment: To clarify, if today was 7/5/2017, you'd want to see bug counts for 6/5-11, 6/12-18, 6/19-25, 6/26-30?

Comment: @JacobMaki Exactly. A we get the count of items very easily for area/line charts, I want to get the same things with created items during one day or one week.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-by-date-or-current-iteration) on querying by date, I don't think you'll be able to accomplish this chart the way you'd like.  The only date querying options are @Today, a specific date, or @CurrentIteration.  There's no variable defining a prior week.  To accomplish what you're after, you'd have to hard code the dates in to the query used by the chart and then update them every week.

You might be able to accomplish what you're after using the SSRS reports.  There are [out of the box reports](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/sql-reports/reporting-services-reports) and you have the ability to [create your own](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/sql-reports/create-and-manage-reporting-services-reports).